# SQL Server query to get values in alphabetical order

Tags: sql-server

In my sql table i have some data as below,

```
ItamName
-----
Småsenter (Sandvika Småsenter)
Brilleland
Game
Name It
```

I have written query as below,

```
SELECT 
(Select I.ItamName from  ItemMaster I where I.ItemId=A.ItemName and I.LanguageId='no' 
and I.SiteId='sandvikas') as elementname,
sum(clicks) as click from Analytics A
where ItemType='Shop' and DateOfEvent >='2013-10-01' and DateOfEvent<='2013-10-31' 
and SiteName='sandvikas'
group by ItemName order by click desc, ItemName Asc  FOR XML RAW('Table'),ROOT('NewDataSet')
```

which gives me output as

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table elementname="Brilleland" click="2" />
  <Table elementname="Name It" click="2" />
  <Table elementname="Småsenter (Sandvika Småsenter)" click="1" />
  <Table elementname="Game" click="1" />
</NewDataSet>
```

There are some special character also in data.I want my xml data in alphabetical order s below,

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table elementname="Brilleland" click="2" />
<Table elementname="Game" click="1" />
  <Table elementname="Name It" click="2" />
  <Table elementname="Småsenter (Sandvika Småsenter)" click="1" />
</NewDataSet>
```

Regards
Sangeetha

Answer (score 2):

Your ORDER BY, as written in your query, will sort by click first then ItemName.  If you want it reversed, reverse the ORDER BY:

`ORDER BY ItemName ASC, click DESC`